# redirect output from interface?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I am echoing an AT command to a modem interface (`/dev/ttyUSB3`) and the command runs successfully.

For instance the below command works and has an output of `OK`:

```
echo -e "ATZ\r" > /dev/ttyUSB3
```

I can see this by having another terminal with `cat /dev/ttyUSB3` active.

How do I, instead of using `cat` (eg use one command to send a command and get output back), redirect the output `OK` to a variable or file so that I can process data returned from the modem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the serial device much like a normal file. The only difference is that it needs some ioctl()s to do the speed and control line setup.

So don't use `os.system("echo` ... but `f = open('/dev/ttyUSB3', 'rw')` and then `f.write()` and `f.read()`.

In theory you could use `ioctl()` to set the speed and so on, but at that stage it's simply easier to use pySerial than to do all of the parameter marshalling yourself. `ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB3', baudrate=9600, timeout=1, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)` with `ser.write()` and `ser.read()`.

Note that you should use udev to set a unique name for the serial port, rather than hard-coding /dev/ttyUSB3. Here's how to do that for a [single USB/RS-232 adapter](http://vk5tu.livejournal.com/24442.html) and here's how to do that for a [multiport USB/RS-232 adapter](http://vk5tu.livejournal.com/48139.html).

Comment: thank you, that is perfect. I should have mentioned python in my OP. If I do as you suggest re naming ports, it would think any usb0-9 was a modem? I will have a few other usb interfaces that are not, so is it about finding a unique parameter in that type of interface?

Answer (score 0):

```
read modem_output < /dev/ttyUSB3
```

Comment: I may have phrased it badly. How would I do this in one command in one terminal? So i would have `echo -e "ATZ\r" > /dev/ttyUSB3` but also some way to redirect the results? Is that possible? Or do I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: @Paul I don't know what you mean by "redirect". Something must read the data from the modem. In your example that was done by `cat`. But if the shell reads the data itself then there is no need for redirection. There is input redirection in this case, though.

Comment: By redirect I mean store in a variable/file. I want the data stored after it is read from the modem so that I can manipulate it. I am using python to make the call `os.system("echo -e...")`. Now what confuses me is do i have to use this read command concurrently in python to running the os.system call or how would I know which data is associated with which command?

Comment: Sorry if this is confusing, I am struggling getting my thoughts across.

Comment: @Paul You open the file `/dev/ttyUSB3` in Python and read from it. Python questions should not be asked here but on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt mean for it to devolve into python but it makes sense that I should have